# onClick Event For Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I have more than 30 picture box in a windows form named

```
PictureBox1
PictureBox2
PictureBox3
.....so on
```

I am having to write the same procedure for click function for every single one of them.
I just want to be able to write a single handler that would handle the click events for all the PictureBox and call the same function.

---

***For a rough technical example.. Sorry for the JavaScript Format***

---

```
picturebox.onclick(){
var a=get_index(this); //gets address of the clicked picturebox
somefunction(a);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple click events with same Sub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323397/how-to-handle-multiple-click-events-with-same-sub)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `Handles` keyword, which is the default, typical way to handle events from controls, you can add multiple event names to the `Handles` clause, for instance:

```
Private Sub OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click
    ' Handles click events from PictureBox1, PictureBox2, and PictureBox3
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can declare the event handler method without the `Handles` clause, and then manually attach it to the events yourself, like this:

```
Private Sub OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' ...
End Sub

' ...

AddHandler PictureBox1.Click, AddressOf OnClick
AddHandler PictureBox2.Click, AddressOf OnClick
AddHandler PictureBox3.Click, AddressOf OnClick
```

Or, if you have list of picture box controls, you could add the event handlers in a loop, like this:

```
Dim myPictureBoxes() As PictureBox = {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3}
For Each i As PictureBox in myPictureBoxes
    AddHandler i.Click, AddressOf OnClick
Next
```

Or, you could access them from your form's `Controls` collection by name:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 30
    Dim c As Control = Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i.ToString())
    AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf OnClick
Next
```

Bear in mind, however, if you do manually call `AddHandler`, you need to also call `RemoveHandler` to later detach the event handler.

It seems odd, on the surface, to have so many picture boxes like that, though.  You may want to consider custom-drawing your content in a single control or look into dynamically loading the controls at run-time.