# Merge private subs that do the same thing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, mouseevent

I have a few private subs that do the same thing (change `ForeColor` on `MouseEnter`) and so was wondering if they can be merged/combined some how to create less coding?

**Example as is now:**

```
Private Sub FooBar_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FooBar.MouseEnter
        FooBar.ForeColor = Color.White
    End Sub

Private Sub FooBar2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FooBar2.MouseEnter
        FooBar2.ForeColor = Color.White
    End Sub
```

Comment: if you **move** the HANDLES clause from one to the other, you will have one handler.  inside it you will want to use `sender` rather than the explicit control name

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple click events with same Sub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323397/how-to-handle-multiple-click-events-with-same-sub)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub FooBar_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FooBar.MouseEnter, FooBar2.MouseEnter
    FooBar.ForeColor = Color.White
    FooBar2.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Yep. Just separate the handlers with a comma.

---

This became apparent after the comments below my answer. If you're not wanting to combine events, or at least both colors change when either form control triggers the event, you'll need an if statement to check to see which form control was triggered. This really doesn't save you too much coding in terms of characters, but I guess it saves you an extra event handling function. E.g.:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    If Button1.Focused Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If

    If Button2.Focused Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Blue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That will set the forecolor for `FooBar` on the `FooBar2` mouse enter event - not what the OP wants

Comment: This only partially answers the question.  FooBar2's ForeColor will never be set by this method.

Comment: If he's wanting to do it in one line, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: you made it worse: the OP is using `MouseEnter` which means some other control may have the focus.  In fact, we have no idea if `FooBar` can get the focus (what if it is a label?).

Comment: Only she knows whether or not whatever control she's using can be focused. I simply gave the option to merge handlers, as well as the possible option for checking for each.

Comment: I have foobar1/5 each have `MouseEnter` (change color) and `MouseLeave` (change back to original state).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of controls foobars are but here is an example with buttons:

```
Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) handles Button1.click, Button2.Click, ... ,ButtonN.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
 End Sub
```