# How to make a mousemove event for multiple labels with one sub procedure?

Tags: vb.net, label, mousemove

I have the following code for a project I'm working in class and I need to copy it about 9 times in total. the only thing that will change each time is the category number and the label name by 1. Do I HAVE to create a mousemove event inidividually for each or is there a way to do it in one sub procedure? I don't care if it is harder, or less efficient I would just like to see if it is possible and how. Thank you.

```
Private Sub lbl1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lbl1.MouseMove
    category = 1
    scoreRoll()
    lbl1.Text = score
End Sub
```

It has been said this may be a duplicate. If someone could tell me how to do that same thing with mousemove instead of click that would be perfect. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple click events with same Sub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323397/how-to-handle-multiple-click-events-with-same-sub)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå okay but I am not clicking so how do I do the same thing with a mousemove instead?

Comment: apply the same *principle*.  examine the answer and apply the concept to your particular situation

Comment: You're kidding right? The concept is the same. Replace `Click` with `MouseMove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple controls can share the same event. You just need to check the `sender` variable to see which one it was and process appropriately:

```
Private Sub lbl_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lbl1.MouseMove, lbl2.MouseMove, lbl3.MouseMove, lbl4.MouseMove, lbl5.MouseMove, lbl6.MouseMove, lbl7.MouseMove, lbl8.MouseMove, lbl9.MouseMove
    Dim lbl As Label = CType(sender, Label)

    category = CInt(lbl.Name.Replace("lbl", ""))
    scoreRoll()
    lbl.Text = score
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't comprehend the other page that was considered a "duplicate".

Comment: @user1486297 the answer by Mr Hall is absolutely identical