# Highlight textbox in Forms when mouse selected/focus on textbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, highlight

I want to ask if how could I change a textbox color when I highlighted for each textbox in form controls.

For example if I have 50+ textbox, its really hard for me to code 50+ textbox each right?

So is there anyway I could set this in a single function?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Alvin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple click events with same Sub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323397/how-to-handle-multiple-click-events-with-same-sub)

Comment: Sorry,thats not what i meant.  I tried that code but it doesn't work.   I have code here for the textbox however I need the code to simplify it.  I want it everytime I select a textbox the backcolor changes its color.  I don't want to code every single textbox with textbox1_enter.  I want a recursive textbox in all my forms with 50+ textbox with each single click on textbox it changes its color.  Let me know if you don't understand.  THanks.

Comment: I don't understand a thing. Do you want the currently selected TextBox to have a different background color? Also, you should probably show the relevant parts of that code.

Comment: You might consider making a custom control of just a textbox that sets the backcolor upon focus and changes it back to it's normal backcolor on lostfocus. This way instead of the standard textbox, you would use your textbox, giving you this ability.

Comment: I agree with Charles May - You can extend TextBox, and then override OnFocus.

Comment: Just connect them all to the same Enter event and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new class and inherit from textbox.
Alter the events in your textbox class and use it instead of the normal textbox.

```
Public Class MTB
Inherits TextBox

     Private Sub MTB_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
           BackColor = Color.Aqua

     End Sub
End Class
```

After you rebuild the project, the MTB object will be waiting for you in the toolbox.

Comment: Like  Charles May and vbnet3d said. :)